# Is the Tensorproduct by defintion distributive?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

The tensor product of two vector is defined from their decomposition on the bases. More precisely, if
$x=\sum_{b\in B_V} x_b\,b \in V \quad \text{and}\quad y=\sum_{c\in B_W} y_c\,c \in W$
are vectors decomposed on their respective bases, then the tensor product is
\begin{align}
x\otimes y&=\left(\sum_{b\in B_V} x_b\,b\right) \otimes \left(\sum_{c\in B_W} y_c\,c\right)\\
&=\sum_{b\in B_V}\sum_{c\in B_W} x_b y_c\, b\otimes c.
\end{align}

Why am I able to pull out the sums? I know that scalars can be factored out, but this does not hold for sums of scalars?

Comment: Does the word "bilinear" ring a bell?

Comment: Is it that simple

Comment: But if you would consider mappings from the space to tensor product into another tensor product space, then the mapping is not bi linear?

Comment: This looks like the definition of the tensor products of two vectors.